# Application crashes when UIActionSheet is called

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I am writing an app for iPad. In this app I have to use a Share button on the navigation bar on all the screens. I have applied the Share button on my Home class. I wrote the following code to apply button on the navigation bar:

```
CGRect frame5 = CGRectMake(835.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
UIImage *buttonImage5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ShareIcon.png"];
UIButton *ShareButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
ShareButton.frame = frame5;
[ShareButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage5 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
ShareButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
ShareButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
[ShareButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actionSheet) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[ShareButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:ShareButton];
```

The share button is used to Email or print a screen. For this purpose I have used UIActionSheet. I wrote the following method to apply UIActionSheet:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(id)sender
{
    UIActionSheet *popup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Email", @"Print", nil];
    [popup showFromRect:CGRectMake(720.0, 3.0, 40.0, 40.0) inView:[self view] animated:TRUE];
    [popup showFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender animated:TRUE];
    [popup release];
}
```

This method is applied on the Share button. When I build and run my app, there is no error or warning, i.e. the build is successful. But when I click on the share button the application crashes and it shows following in the debugger console window:

```
[Session started at 2011-10-21 21:26:58 +0530.]
2011-10-21 21:27:03.895 NewBostonEndoscopy[1351:207] -[Home actsht]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6227010
2011-10-21 21:27:03.898 NewBostonEndoscopy[1351:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Home actsht]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6227010'
```

I am not getting why this is happening. Any guess?
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks and regards
Prateek

Comment: What is 'actsht' method? Where this method is invoked. Obviously you're trying to call this selector on a wrong object.

Comment: Thanks Kovpas, I figured that out....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are showing the popup twice, I'm not sure if this is the reason for you crash, but try removing the line

```
[popup showFromRect:CGRectMake(720.0, 3.0, 40.0, 40.0) inView:[self view] animated:TRUE];
```

Answer (score 1):

`[ShareButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actionSheet) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`
change to:
`[ShareButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actionSheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`
The missing ':' after actionSheet is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

As the log says, you are calling `-actsht` on `Home`, which apparently does not implement a method with this name. Try searching your document for `actsht` and see what you meant.

Probably, you used it in a `UIBarButtonItem` initializer, e.g. `-initWithBarButtonSystemItem:target:action:`, and specified a selector for `action` that does not exist. The compiler would not notice this.